# Change event not fired when keydown event (TAB key) modifies element value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given HTML of:

```
<input type="text" id="test" />
```

and JavaScript of:

```
var $test = $('#test');

$test.on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 9) {
        $(event.target).val('change it!');
    }
});

$test.on('change', function(event) {
    alert('I am not called!');
});
```

if I type anything in the input and hit the <kbd>tab</kbd>, why does the `change` event not fire? The `keydown` event fires, and updates the value of the input.

**If I remove the `.val()` call, then `change` does fire.**

At first, I thought this was a jQuery issue (running 1.9.1), but confirmed the same behaviors occur if I use plain JavaScript.

Comment: I managed to find an old bug report for Firefox where the `change` event **is** fired under the same situation. However, the behavior changed from v1.5 to v2.0. Can't find anything similar for Webkit. Ref. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=357021

Answer (score 8):

`change` only fires for changes committed by the user. In other words, using JavaScript to change an element's value in the background doesn't fire `change`.

Tab doesn't actually change the content of the element; it just switches focus. It's coincidental, in some ways, that you're typing tab to change the element's content (you might as well be pressing a button to update it indirectly, which wouldn't fire `change` either).

[The DOM spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-keyboard-event-order) explains why, in your specific case, if you type and tab, the user input is discarded and no change is fired.

Specifically:

> The keyboard events defined in this specification occur in a set order
>   relative to one another,  for any given key:
>
> - keydown
> - keypress (only for keys which produce a character value)
> - Any default actions related to this key
> - keyup

When you press the tab key, `keydown` is triggered. Boom, your event handler is called! The element content is updated by your script -- no change fired because it's script doing it. The user contributed content is wiped out. Now it's time for the browser to perform the default actions associated with tab: take focus away and see whether the element was changed by the user (to fire onchange). Nope, it was changed by the script! No `change` to fire.

Thus, if you remove the `val()` line, you'll notice two things.

1. If you give the element focus and tab off, no `change` is fired -- no change had occurred since tab doesn't change the field content.
2. If you give the element focus and type something and tab off, `change` is fired because during that magical "default actions related to tab" moment, the browser notices the user contributed a change.

Whew!

Comment: I don't see in the spec. where it mentions script-based changes not triggering events. Did you get this from another source?

Comment: Oh, sorry. The Level 3 spec just explains the ordering. The Level 2 spec seems a little ambiguous but the HTML5 spec is more clear that the user (to be precise, the user agent) has to cause the change directly: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#event-input-change

Comment: Tab must be special in this regard because if I remove the existing logic for `keyCode === 9` I can have other keys trigger value-changes on the textbox and when I press tab `change` is fired.

Comment: Yes, that's correct -- tab's special. Unlike those other keys, tab changes focus, triggering the change event immediately. If you intercept the tab at keydown, you're interrupting the normal flow (cf Eli's answer below).

Answer (score 2):

I never did get around to figuring out the why (as the other responders already did), but I did find a solution for you, since you're already using jQuery. Just trigger the change event yourself by using its jQuery method instead of val():

```
var test = $('#test');
test.on('keydown', function(event) {
if (event.keyCode == 9) {
    $(event.target).change(function(){
        this.value = 'change it!';
    });
}
});
test.on('change', function(event) {
    alert('I am not called!');
});
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqZ9/).

Comment: The library we are using (http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/) which led to this question appears to have been forked/updated with the same concept (https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/6274955f34756688e2650be16f11dd2fb23321df).

Comment: While I agree this approach is functional, it does require the `change`-event function to validate the value has actually changed. Otherwise, you could have _phantom_ code execution depending on the function implementation (i.e. tracking number of changes and user is pressing arrows keys).

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the value before the `keyup` of the tab.  At `keyup` the change event would be triggered.  But since you changed the value during the `keydown` handler, by the time it loses focus, the value is back to what it was previously.

To see this, change your jquery from `keydown` to `keyup` and you'll see the event fires (and you'll also see the event fires AND THEN the `keyup` triggers and changes text back).